# Getting a TypeError for unknown reason

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, error-handling, nonetype

I have the following code (it is a calculator program):

```
import pygame
import operator
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 711))
pygame.display.set_caption("INIX")
Calculator_Screen = pygame.image.load("Calculator.Screen.png")
op = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv,
}
def calculator_module():

    events = list(pygame.event.get())
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Calculator = False
            return Calculator
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x > 17 and x < 107 and y > 445 and y < 530:     #1
                return "1"
            elif x > 108 and x < 198 and y > 445 and y < 530:     #2
                return "2"
            elif x > 199 and x < 290 and y > 445 and y < 530:     #3
                return "3"
            elif x > 17 and x < 107 and y > 336 and y < 443:     #4
                return "4"
            elif x > 108 and x < 198 and y > 336 and y < 443:     #5
                return "5"
            elif x > 199 and x < 290 and y > 336 and y < 443:     #6
                return "6"
            elif x > 17 and x < 107 and y > 268 and y < 334:     #7
                return "7"
            elif x > 108 and x < 198 and y > 268 and y < 334:     #8
                return "8"
            elif x > 199 and x < 290 and y > 268 and y < 334:     #9
                return "9"
            elif x > 17 and x < 107 and y > 532 and y < 620:     #0
                return "0"
            elif x > 199 and x < 290 and y > 532 and y < 620:     #=
                return "="
            elif x > 292 and x < 380 and y > 532 and y < 620:     #+
                return "+"
            elif x > 292 and x < 380 and y > 445 and y < 530:     #-
                return "-"
            elif x > 292 and x < 380 and y > 268 and y < 334:     #/
                return "/"
            elif x > 292 and x < 380 and y > 336 and y < 443:     #x
                return "*"

Calculator = True
while Calculator:
    screen.blit(Calculator_Screen, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    events = list(pygame.event.get())
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Calculator = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x > 180 and x < 218 and y > 670 and y < 708:
                Calculator = False

            while True:
                current = 0
                num1 = 0
                num2 = 0

                while current not in op:
                    num1 = num1*10 + int(current)
                    current = calculator_module()
                last_op = current
                current = 0
                while current != "=":
                    if current in op:
                        num1 = op[last_op](num1, num2)
                        last_op = current
                        num2 = 0
                    else:
                        num2 = num2*10 + int(current)
                    current = calculator_module()
                res = op[last_op](num1, num2)
                print(res)
```

Whenever I run this code and press on a button I get the following error:
`num1 = num1*10 + int(current)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`
I dont know why I am getting this error as I don't use `None` at all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take note that there are cases where your function `calculator_module()` does not `return` (for instance when `events` is empty), and therefore *implicitly* returns `None`.
In that case you get `None` as your `current` and this causes the error.

To fix this make sure your function `calculator_module()` returns a value in all execution paths.

**Edit:** for instance:

```
def calculator_module():
    events = list(pygame.event.get())
    if not events: # check if the list is empty
        return 0
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Calculator = False
            return Calculator
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        ...
        ... # all your other elif go here
        ...
        else:
            return 0
```

**Edit #2:** I should note that is looks very weird that you are doing:

```
for event in events:
```

Because you actually will never iterate over more than a **single** event. Since you will `return` in case... So you should reconsider your logic flow.

Comment: Is it in part of my `calculator_module` before all the `if` statements?

Comment: It can be, as I said, if `events` is empty. Or if `event.type != pygame.QUIT` and also `event.type != pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` for all `events`

Comment: Can you show me what to do because I understand the error but still a bit confused about what to do.

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you. But it **doesn't mean** that what I show will make the code work *as expected*, but it will fix the `None` error.

Comment: Ok thats fine with me.

Comment: I fixed what you told me to fix but I am still getting the `None` error.

Comment: There is no way you will be getting that **exact** error. Maybe it's a different error and you overlooked?

Comment: No I am still getting the exact same error and I am using `for event in events` because I am using this piece of code in another program with other events.

Comment: Go through your code with a debugger. I am 100% certain that if you copied my code correctly there is no chance that function will return `None`. (make **sure** you copied the `elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:` correctly, because you had it as `if` and not `elif`...)

Comment: To be 1000% sure, just add `return 0` at the end of the function. That way it **has** to return something of value eventually (even though it already does in my mind)...

Comment: I went through my code with a debugger and I still get that error(I am going to edit my question with the code that I have now).

Comment: Nevermind adding `return 0` at the end of my function has fixed it!

Comment: I you have a minute do you mind helping me for something about this same code?

Comment: I would love to, but please create a new question for any further problems. You can leave a link to it here if you would like and I will get to it when I can :)

Comment: Here is my question, I did get an answer from it but it did not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017586/getting-weird-outputs-from-my-calculator-program